# Not able to install nginx?

Tags: nginx

I was able to install nginx's latest stable version (1.8.0) on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop PC, by using following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

But when am trying the same commands on DragonBoard 410c it's showing the following error.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nginx : Depends: nginx-full (>= 1.8.0-1+vivid1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 nginx-light (>= 1.8.0-1+vivid1) but it is not going to be installed or
                 nginx-extras (>= 1.8.0-1+vivid1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: nginx-full (< 1.8.0-1+vivid1.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                 nginx-light (< 1.8.0-1+vivid1.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
                 nginx-extras (< 1.8.0-1+vivid1.1~) but it is not going to be installed

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/main arm64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_vivid_main_binary-arm64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/universe arm64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/ports.ubuntu.com_ubuntu-ports_dists_vivid_universe_binary-arm64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

We have flashed Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid) release of linaro on DragonBoard 410c.

```
root@linaro-alip:~# apt-cache policy nginx nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras
nginx:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.0-1+vivid1
  Version table:
     1.8.0-1+vivid1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/ vivid/main arm64 Packages
     1.6.2-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/main arm64 Packages
nginx-full:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6.2-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.6.2-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/universe arm64 Packages
nginx-light:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6.2-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.6.2-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/universe arm64 Packages
nginx-extras:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6.2-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1.6.2-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/universe arm64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy nginx nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras`

Comment: Is the DragonBoard 410c ARM architecture? Check if the PPA actually supplies ARM builds (default only i386/amd64).

Comment: @gertvdijk The PPA supports armf

Comment: Added "apt-cache policy nginx nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras" to the question.